# How do I make the text and the image inline together?

Tags: html, css

I'm working my way through an online course and run into a problem. We are supposed to create a site that looks like this:
[Goal Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgZmT.png)

Currently, my website looks like this:
[My Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOfGg.png)

Here is the HTML and CSS code I am trying to amend:

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <img class="logo" src="./assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>We are a <span style="color: darkblue;">Creative</span> Design Agency</h1>
    <div class="left card"><img class="tile-image-left tile-image" src="./assets/images/beautiful.jpg" alt="hand and flower in water">
      <h2 class="card-title">Beauty</h2>
      <p class="card-text">We strive to create the most beautiful websites for all your needs. Working closely with you
        to
        design and
        develop an amazing website for your business.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="right card"><img class="tile-image-right tile-image" src="./assets/images/construction.jpg" alt="metal structure">
      <h2 class="card-title-right">Construction</h2>
      <p class="card-text-right">Built by our team of professional developers, we ensure the most rigourous and modern websites. Built from
        scratch using HTML and CSS. Only the best for you.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Create. Develop. Design.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

```
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: #faf9f6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 95vh;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

footer {
  text-align: right;
  color: midnightblue;
}

.tile-image{
  height: 200px;
}

.tile-image-left{
float: left;
clear: both;
}
```

I've tried to set the div's, images, and text to 'inline-block' but that hasn't worked.

I've also tried to float the text by the images, but found that the 2nd image always seems to move out of place, as seen by the image it is directly below my first image, but I need them to be side to side.

I'm not sure how to tackle this so I'd appreciate the help if you can spare the time.

Regards,
Proton

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `left` and `right` cards inside a parent div (`.cards` in the below example). Then, wrap your text content inside a parent (`aside` in the example).

Then it's just a case of setting both to `flex` display.

You'll have to add margins/paddings to get it exactly like the design.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  background-color: #faf9f6;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 95vh;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

footer {
  text-align: right;
  color: midnightblue;
}

.tile-image{
  height: 200px;
}

.tile-image-left{
float: left;
clear: both;
}

.cards {
  display:flex;
}
.card {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">

    <div class="cards">
      <div class="left card">
        <img class="tile-image-left tile-image" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="hand and flower in water">
        <aside>
          <h2 class="card-title">Beauty</h2>
          <p class="card-text">We strive to create the most beautiful websites for all your needs. Working closely with you
        to
        design and
        develop an amazing website for your business.</p>
        </aside>
    </div>

    <div class="right card">
      <img class="tile-image-right tile-image" src="https://picsum.photos/500/500" alt="metal structure">
      <aside>
        <h2 class="card-title-right">Construction</h2>
        <p class="card-text-right">Built by our team of professional developers, we ensure the most rigourous and modern websites. Built from
        scratch using HTML and CSS. Only the best for you.</p>
      </aside>
    </div>
    </div>
    

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this in my project which I have implemented but I am presenting small portion of it.

```css
/*
SPACING SYSTEM (px)
2 / 4 / 8 / 12 / 16 / 24 / 32 / 48 / 64 / 80 / 96 / 128

FONT SIZE SYSTEM (px)
10 / 12 / 14 / 16 / 18 / 20 / 24 / 30 / 36 / 44 / 52 / 62 / 74 / 86 / 98
*/

/* 
MAIN COLOR: #087f5b
GREY COLOR: #343a40
*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* ------------------------ */
/* GENERAL STYLES */
/* ------------------------ */
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: #343a40;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #087f5b;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header,
section {
  margin-bottom: 96px;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  /* 24 / 30 / 36 */
}

.grid-3-cols {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  column-gap: 80px;
}

.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
  background-color: #087f5b;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;

  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
  background-color: #099268;
}

.btn--big {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

.btn--small {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 12px;
}

/* ------------------------ */
/* COMPONENT STYLES */
/* ------------------------ */

/* HEADER */
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  column-gap: 80px;
  margin-top: 64px;
}

.header-text-box {
  align-self: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  /* 44 / 52 / 62 */

  /* text-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
}

.header-text {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* FEATURES */
.features-icon {
  stroke: #087f5b;
  width: 32px;
  heigh: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.features-title {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.features-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

/* TESTIMONIAL */
.testimonial-section {
  background-color: #087f5b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.testimonial-box {
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  align-self: center;
}

.testimonial-box h2 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  /* 20 / 24 / 30 */
  font-size: 24px;
}

.testimonial-text {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #e6fcf5;
}

.testimonial-author {
  color: #c3fae8;
}

/* CHAIRS */
.chair {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.chair img {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.chair-box {
  padding: 32px;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.chair-details {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}

.chair-details li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.chair-details li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.chair-icon {
  stroke: #087f5b;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.chair-price {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

footer {
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #495057;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Lisbon Chair Shop</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <div class="header-text-box">
          <h1>We design and build better chairs, for a better life</h1>
          <p class="header-text">
            In a small shop in the heart of Lisbon, we spend our days
            relentlessly perfecting the chair. The result is a perfect blend of
            beauty and comfort, that will have a lasting impact on your health.
          </p>
          <a class="btn btn--big" href="#">Shop chairs</a>
        </div>
        <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/598e35994ab8482c0d6946e0/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/phonepicutres-TA.jpg" alt="Photo" />
      </header>

     
  </body>
</html>
```

It has HTML and CSS both and is presented as a demo.